# What is required to run a c# console application on a computer

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have created a simple c# console application with .net framework 2.0 that uses MySql. What steps should I do in order to get the program run on another computer(Windows Server 2008)?

I already have MS .Net framework Clent Profile and MS .Net framework Clent Profile Extended installed.

Should I install .net framework 2.0 Service pack too on the other pc?

Thanks.

Comment: yes only the net framework must be installed. (and of course MySql)

Comment: Note that if the target client subscribes to Windows Updates, you won't actually need to worry about physically deploying the framework - it'll be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have .Net framework 2.0 installed on the computer. Also make sure you have the .Net dlls required for making connection. If your application is going to use the local machine as MySQL server then, you may have to intall MySQL on the client machine as well,  or you can make an installer with MySQL installation included. You can use [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or you may check out the following thread [Deploy MySQL Server + DB with .Net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378/deploy-mysql-server-db-with-net-application)

Comment: I already have MS .Net framework Clent Profile and MS .Net framework Clent Profile Extended installed.

Should I install .net framework 2.0 Service pack too on the other pc?

Comment: @user735647, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19 download from here and install

Comment: @user735647, what is the target framework in your application ?

Comment: Thanks but I am unable to open MS sites due to some reason. Please advice on this. Do I need to install MS net framework 2.0 Service pack too?

Comment: @user735647, Even after installing Client Profile and Client Profile extended, its not working ? it should

Answer (score 2):

You just need .Net Framework 2.0 or later to be installed on the machine.

It would would be better to make an installer.

Answer (score 1):

Environment - .Net Framework.

Version - Same as one or higher in which you app is targeted.

Why i said no particular version number because what if you app is in 4.0 and you have 2.0 installed?

That's why same version or higher.