# Deploying database with my windows form application

Tags: c#, mysql

I have made a RSS reader winform app which uses a mysql database to store urls. 
If I publish the application, the setup works fine in my computer as i have MySQL and the database within my computer. 
But how can i deploy the Mysql database with my application?
Does whoever installs my app also needs to install MySQL, or is there any other way to do around?

Comment: u might consider a distributable db such as sqlite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378/deploy-mysql-server-db-with-net-application

Comment: How many ppl will be using your system? Is it intended that several users will be all accessing the same Database. Its a very important aspect.

Answer (score 0):

U should try to include a sql script to crate the database and tables u need. so that everyone who will use your application only hast to enter his logon data for a mysql database. So there is no need to install a complete mysql with your application. 
In general the DB does not have to be on the same system as the application.

Comment: So you're saying that in order for the application to work the user must have a MySQL server available?

Comment: I'm pretty sure nowadays nearly everybody has access to at least one mysql server if he has some webspace somewhere.

Comment: Sure.. but do his customers have that? What's to say the customer's "webspace" isn't hosted on a Windows box with MS SQL?