# VB.NET: Is windows form application project deployment with Mysql database is feasible?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, deployment

I am a PHP developer and not so familiar with to **VB.NET**.
I am developing a **system for Tailor Shop**.
I have facing following problems regarding database……please help ……

> **I tried SQL Server CE:** I found that this is not helpful to me because its limitations and most of the times it shown me the errors.
>   (One of the errors is:"Expression evaluation caused an overflow. [Name of function (if known) =] ")

> **I tried SQLite :** I found that SQLite db is also not helpful to me (again due to its limitation) because this database does not support data with other than English letters.
>   ***The Case:*** I want to store person name in my regional language i.e. - Hindi (name = "विक्रम") but SQLite database does not support it (it shows "?????").  
>   
>   (I thought – SQL Server CE or SQLite would be easy for project deployment)

**I want to try Mysql database now:

This is what I love very much to work with. This is perfect database for my needs.**

*My Question Is:-*

### Is windows form application (standalone) project with Mysql database easy to deploy on client machine? And How?

Answer (score 1):

You can make add a Setup and Deployment project to the vb.net solution, and include MySql in it. One way to do this is copy the MySQL install file with your project installation, then when your application runs, if it doesn't find MySQL, ask the user if it should be installed.

Comment: OK googled same but, MySQL Server is near about 200MB while my s/w is hardly 5MB.  
Is it possible to attach only MySQL Database Files to project (like SQLite Or SQL S CE : File based database) ??

Comment: Here are some options for that. It's not as simple as some database systems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378/deploy-mysql-server-db-with-net-application