# How to include MySQL Database in compiling VB.NET application

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using MySQL database on my project and never had experience compiling vb.net application that includes database. So i want to know how to include or embed the MySQL database in making executable file of your application. Thanks!

Comment: Not an easy task... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378/deploy-mysql-server-db-with-net-application, do you have considered to use a different database? (Sql Server Compact, SQLite, LocalDB even Access for stand-alone installations)

Comment: @Steve What can you recommend that is good to be centralized database?

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the solution and load it:`'By RightClicking on solution and click add/existing item'`

```
Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\database.mdf")
```

If i hadn't solved your problem give me more information.